# A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I get this error when I try to access a specific page. I have also tried including the below line in the web.config:

```
<httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="&lt;,&gt;,*,%,&amp;,:,\,?" />
```

The url of the page looks like this: `domain.com/Customer/CustomerPage/Canada/GTA%20Safety%20&%20Compliance`

The .net version the server is running on is 4.5.

Comment: the ampersand is causing problems

Comment: what should I use instead?

Comment: try url encoding it.

Comment: @psyoptica can't you generate URL-friendly strings for your pages? `domain.com/customer/customerpage/canada/gta-safety-compliance`

Comment: I don't really know how to do that but I'll read up on it.